# how to populate dropdown based on onother in wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

i'm new on javascript and i have a problem that i am creating a new WordPress plugin and i have tow dropdowns both are getting their value from database
and the second values are populated based on the first one
i have the following code and the hard part that i have to put all these things on a $content as return value

```
 function water_bill_form(){
 $content  .=    '<select style="    name="c1"
class="required-entry" id="category" onchange="javascript: dynamicdropdown();">';
$content  .=
'<option id="subcategory" >  pleas select</option>';
             while ( $row = $projresult->fetch() ) 
             {
                $content  .= '<option style="color: black; background-color:#f9f9f9;" id="subcategory"; value="'.$row['city_name'].'">'.$row['city_name'].'</option>';   }
 $content  .= '</select>';
 $content .='<script language="javascript" > 
 function dynamicdropdown(){
 
 }
 </script>';

}
  return $content;}
      add_shortcode('water','water_bill_form');
```

obviously have connected to the database before all of this .
now i couldn't find out how populate the second dropdown from database based on the chosen value  in the dynamicdropdown function
i stopped here because i have found a lot of different solutions but couldn't really apply any

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **Ajax** for this.
For example: if you want to get state options for a selected city your code should be somewhat like below :

```
function waterBillForm(){
    $content  .= '<select name="c1" class="required-entry" 
    id="category" onchange="dynamicdropdown()">';
    $content  .= '<option id="subcategory" > please select</option>';
        while ( $row = $projresult->fetch() ) 
        {
            $content  .= '<option style="color: black; 
            background-color:#f9f9f9;" id="subcategory"; 
            value="'.$row['city_name'].'">'.$row['city_name'].'</option>';
        }
    $content  .= '<option id="state" > please select</option>';
    $content  .= '</select>';
    $content .='<script language="javascript" > 
        function dynamicdropdown(){
            var city_id = "YOUR SELECTED CITY ID";
            jQuery.get(AJAX-URL + "?action=get_states", {
                city_id: city_id
            }, function(response) {
                jQuery("#state").empty().html(response)
            })
        }
    </script>';
    return $content;
}

add_shortcode('water','waterBillForm');

add_action('wp_ajax_get_states', 'get_states');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_states', 'get_states');
function get_states()
{
    $city_id = $_REQUEST['city_id'];
    return "YOUR NEW STATE OPTIONS FOR THE CITY";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but how i can get the selected id in my situation ,and where i should put <select> tag for the second dropdown?? @Kamrul Sajib